# PHP Mysqli fail to getaddress

Tags: php, mysqli

I get the  following error when I try to establish a connection to my database using mysqli:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\emarps\database\getuserdetails.php on line 4
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\emarps\database\getuserdetails.php on line 4
>
> Connect failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such
>   host is known.

Below is my php code for connecting to the database:

```
$host_name = "127.0.0.1";
$database = "db565263480";
$user_name = "dbo565263480";
$password = "emarps2015!";
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user_name, $password, $database);
// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you tried to connect it using `$host_name`?

Comment: Yes I did but still it fails @MubinKhalid

Comment: @user689017 it seems unlikely you'd get exactly the same error replacing `'localhost'` with `$host_name` in the code you've provided.

Comment: what do you get if `ping localhost` from your shell ?